# Typescript - Incorrectly inferring 'never'

Tags: typescript, type-inference

This is a basic use-case: Initializing a variable with null then changing the value in some nested loop/function:

```js
let a: number | null = null;
[1].forEach(() => {
  a = 1;
});

if (a != null)
  a.toFixed(); // Error: Property 'toFixed' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

However typescript infers `a`'s type to be `never`. I would assume that without the `if` it would assume it to be `null | number` in which case I could get an error stating the property does not exist on null, but why is it assuming it to be never based on just the initial assignment value.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This would mean for typescript to know exactly what `forEach` does at runtime, which it doesn't. Also keep in mind that forEach can be modified to do a different thing so it's pointless to train typescript to know that.

Comment: TS does not analyze what happens inside callbacks. Because it is hard to know when callbacks will be invoked (they may not be invoked at all).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure that `a` has a value there, than you can put the `!` after the variable

```
let a: number | null = null;
[1].forEach(() => {
  a = 1;
});

if (a !== null)
  a!.toFixed(); //
```

I would not use `null` thought but `undefined`, so no need to use `!`

```
let a: number | undefined;
[1].forEach(() => {
  a = 1;
});

if (a) { // <-- if undefined or 0
  a.toFixed(); // No problem here
}
```

Also as recommendation use `!==` not `!=`

Comment: Good point. Use `undefined` instead of `null` is a good advice.

Comment: If you initialize the variable to undefined, it no longer works. So not only TypeScript doesn't know (which is fine), it is certain it can never be assigned (which is incorrect).
let a: number | undefined = undefined;
if(a) { // a is Never }

Comment: Why would you initialize a variable using undefined?

Answer (score 5):

Late to the party, but here are my 2 cents.

## Remark to the accepted answer

```
if (a) {
  a.toFixed(); // No problem here
}
```

note, that the if block will **not** be invoked when `a` is `0`.

- to fix this, use `if (a !== undefined)`
- otherwise (when you really don't want to handle `0` you are better off initializing  `a` to `0` like so:

```
    let a = 0; // typescript will infer the type number
    ...
    if (a) {
      // a is of type number and !== 0
    }
```

## Answer to a comment

> Why would you initialize a variable using undefined?

People sometimes do this, because some tools (IDE, linters, ..) report errors/warnings otherwise.

e.g. here is a warning when you use IntelliJ IDEA with the default typescript settings:
[image]

I recommend to deactivate these checks, since an uninitialized variable in javascript always has the value `undefined`: i.e. in some other languages (i.e. C), the variable might have some random "garbage" value.

Quote from [MDN: Global_Objects/undefined#description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined#description)

> A variable that has not been assigned a value is of type undefined.

And for all other values (i.e. values that are **not** `undefined`), the typescript compiler will  show an error:
`TS2454: Variable 'xxx' is used before being assigned.`

## Answer to the original question

```
let a: number | null = null;
[1].forEach(() => {
  a = 1;
});

if (a != null)
  a.toFixed(); // Error: Property 'toFixed' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

This only happens when the compiler option `strictNullChecks` is on.

This quote describes the reason well ([Quote Reference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10721#issuecomment-245046962))

> While strictNullChecks implies that it is just checking for usage of variables that might be undefined or null it really turns the compiler into a very pessimistic mode, where when there are no contextual way of inferring the type, it will choose the narrowest type, instead of the widest type,

This means, in detail:

- since the typescript compiler is not smart enough to know if the forEach loop is invoked (and thus a value is assigned), it takes the pessimistic approach and assumes that `x` remains `null`
- thus, the type of `x` after the loop is `null` (not `number | null` as we might expect)
- now, the final if block checks if `x !=== null` which can never be the case (since typescript assumes that x **is** `null` when the if-statement is executed. Thus the type of `x` inside of the if-statement is `never`
- so one "solution" is to explicitly tell typescript that you are sure, that the value of `x` is defined by using `x!.toFixed()`

## Misc

### strictNullChecks

When `strictNullChecks` is off, the code works: [TypeScript example: strictNullChecks=off](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false#code/DYUwLgBAhgXBB2BXAtgIxAJwgHwY4wEAvHgQNwCwAUANoCMAugHQBmA9hgKJQDGAFgAoBASmIA+CAG9qEaMQh1KVAL7Cl1AJYsIAqBACEJJAWEzoTMGwBiGgB4gAJiLIQA9K4icMGDnAAKPgAOmGAAnhAA5JY29g4REA5sIADOCGyQILYayZBs8BBhwZHwIABumBFMQA)
I strongly recommend NOT to do that.

### for..of loop

When you use a for..of loop instead of `forEach()` the code works, even when `strictNullChecks` is on: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAhgXBB2BXAtgIxAJwgHwY4wEAvHgQNwBQAZgPZYAUAxjfAM6QCWENVEA2gEYAugEoIAbwoRoxCAMoBfSh170oEAIQkkBEVOgA6MDQBiHAB4gAJvRFkgA)

```
let a: number | null = null;
for (const i of [1]) {
  a = 1;
};
if (a != null)
  a.toFixed();
```

### Other init values

You can also consider other initialization values (instead of `undefined` or `null`): [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAhhC8EAYDcED0qJgJ4AcQGcBjAJwEsdIB3U4YCUgOwDMRjMALKSGU-CAeyaZcICAwCuAWwBGrALAAoANoBGALoA6Jv2IBRKIXYAKIwEo4APggBvRRGhwIKpIoC+plwtJCjMC-ARTO2gNMH4AMVIADxAAEzNPRUVQSGlHADkodJR0YTwiMgoIalp6ZlYOLgg03gEhbDwxKVliRVVNbT0DYzNLG2CYeGc3D0VvCCMAQl5M9KNpUyCFe2lQiOi4hKA)

```
let a = 0; // typescript will infer that a is of type number
[1].forEach(() => {
  a = 1;
});
if (a >= 0)
  a.toFixed();


let b = NaN; // typescript will infer that b is of type number
[1].forEach(() => {
  a = 1;
});
if (!isNaN(b))
  b.toFixed();
```