# Incorrect inference of never

Tags: typescript

Not a duplicate of [Typescript - Incorrectly inferring 'never'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54769781/typescript-incorrectly-inferring-never) (none of the answers there help):

```js
class Status { constructor(public content: string){} }

class Visitor
{
  private status: Status | undefined = undefined;

  visit(tree: Tree) {
    if (tree.value > 7) {
      this.status = new Status("good");
      return; // oops ! forgot this return statement
    }

    this.status = undefined;
    if (tree.left) { tree.left.accept(this); }

    if (this.status === undefined) { return; }
    
    // incorrectly infer this.status to be never
    console.log(this.status.content);
  }
}

class Tree {
  constructor(public value: number, public left?: Tree, public right?: Tree){}
  accept(visitor: Visitor) {
    visitor.visit(this);
  }
}
```

When I compile my code I get an error:

```
% npx tsc --strict main.ts
main.ts:16:29 - error TS2339: Property 'content' does not exist on type 'never'.

16     console.log(this.status.content);
                               ~~~~~~~
```

When I try to use `this.status!.content` nothing changes, I get the same error.

Comment: calling `this.status = undefined;` nullifies the line before. ` this.status = new Status("good"); `
 Your code doesn't make sense.

Comment: Apologies ! I forgot a missing `return` after the `new`, editing now

Comment: For the downvotes, it's a perfect example of https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998

Comment: What is the question here, exactly?  Is it "why is this happening"?  Or is it "how do I fix it?" There are two answers here and they answer different questions, and I think the reason is because this post doesn't actually seem to ask a question.  Could you [edit] to clarify and then we can figure out how to proceed?

Comment: @jcalz I would say the original post was understanding what is going on. By now, I understand the limitations, and found out by myself how to fix them (shown in my answer below).

Comment: Sure, but Stack Overflow questions are only partly for the benefit of the asker. They are also meant to be a resource for future users, so it helps if the question and answer make sense to them also.  Could you please [edit] the question (or do you mind if I do) to make it clear what the question should be, so that we can decide which of the two answers here applies better?

Comment: @jcalz sure, go right ahead and edit. I think that objectively my own answer solved the mentioned problem. The other answer got completely edited. The downvotes were because I left out the return so the code did not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my problem has an easy solution, all the type-checker needed was a little help:

```
this.status = undefined as Status | undefined;
```

Here is the complete file:

```
class Status { constructor(public content: string){} }

class Visitor
{
  private status: Status | undefined = undefined;

  visit(tree: Tree) {
    if (tree.value > 7) {
      this.status = new Status("good"); 
      return;
    }

    this.status = undefined as Status | undefined;
    if (tree.left) { tree.left.accept(this); }

    if (this.status === undefined) { return; }
    
    // incorrectly infer this.status to be never
    console.log(this.status.content);
  }
}

class Tree {
  constructor(public value: number, public left?: Tree, public right?: Tree){}
  accept(visitor: Visitor) {
    visitor.visit(this);
  }
}

const tree = new Tree(2, new Tree(8), new Tree(1));
const visitor = new Visitor();
tree.accept(visitor);
```

This code compiles correctly with `--strict`:

```
$ npx tsc --strict main.ts
$ node main.js
good
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect example for the infamous [issue #9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998).

Typescript makes some tradeoffs on inference. You can see this because of the recursive call you make.

I would suggest you to remove the side effects on visit (do not affect the status in the function), return the status instead.